# RSpec seems to break when the route 'match' statement has a subdirectory (or nested route) listed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

```
it "should match login for existing account" do
  { :get => 'http://www.' + @business.subdomain + '.lvh.me:3000/login' }.should route_to({:controller => "go", :action => "index"})
end
```

---

```
match '/login' => 'admin/calendars#index' # this one should actually work, but fails:

The recognized options <{"controller"=>"errors", "action"=>"handle404", "a"=>"login"}> did not match <{"controller"=>"go", "action"=>"index"}>, difference: <{"controller"=>"go", "action"=>"index", "a"=>"login"}>.
```

The specific controller#route here does exist, but the directory/nested route ('admin/') seems to cause a failure. Even if the route didn't exist it should fail in the same way the next one does, considering that the specified route there ('calendars#index') does not exist. The existence of the resulting routes doesn't matter -- as this is only supposed to test that the mapping works. Any idea how to get around this?

```
  match '/login' => 'calendars#index' #this one fails as expected:

The recognized options <{"controller"=>"calendars", "action"=>"index"}> did not match <{"controller"=>"go", "action"=>"index"}>, difference: <{"controller"=>"go"}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your building of your test route is wrong:

```
it "should match login for existing account" do
  { :get => 'http://www.' + @business.subdomain + '.lvh.me:3000/login' }.should route_to({:controller => "go", :action => "index"})
end
```

should probably read:

```
it "should match login for existing account" do
  { :get => 'http://' + @business.subdomain + '.lvh.me:3000/login' }.should route_to({:controller => "go", :action => "index"})
end
```

as presumably you want to test http://foo.lvh.me/etc not http://www.foo.lvh.me etc